# Multi-line antd alert description

Tags: antd

Is there a way to have a multi-line alert description that also includes HTML (ie `<code>` tags)

It seems that the description is escaped, so any markup or `\n` is rendered literally, eg https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awzNzP?editors=001.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I figured it out.  I failed to notice that the `description` property can be a `ReactNode`, so you can do this

```
descriptionElement = (
  <code>
    Line 1
    <br />
    Line 2
  </code>
)
<Alert message='test' type='info' description={descriptionElement} />
```

[Running version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZEGXN?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

For antd version 4.x

```js
<Alert
      message="Error message"
      description={
        <code>
          console.log("This is code in alert")
          <br />
          console.log("This is code in alert")
          <br />
          console.log("This is code in alert")
        </code>
      }
      type="error"
      showIcon
    />
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]